# Java-Selenium- Image upload

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a image using Selenium WebDriver jar in Eclipse by `sendkeys()` method

- Website url= " http://www.olx.in/posting/?gclid=CjwKEAiA__C1BRDqyJOQ8_Tq230SJABWBSxn2ZaiIvD_GVChb1EKMHZMA-wrkxpJ8_B4pll-j_f89xoCTtnw_wcB&invite=google-in_kwd&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=Account_Level_Sitelink_Post-Free-Ad&Account=3296&Category=Sitelink&Adgroup=Sitelink_5&Keyword=free%20advertisement&MatchType=b&AvgPos=1t1&CreativeID=88437552911&Device=c&UDF=&ef_id=VkferwAAAH6tIhYS:20160212063831:s "

  - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='block'])[1]")).sendKeys("C:/Users/RAMASWAMY/Desktop/ModernDinningPlace.jpg");`

The image is not getting upload and i am not getting any exception in the console even.

Please help me this.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Could be lots of things, we need to know what the error is.

Comment: The image is not getting upload and i am not getting any exception in the console even.

Answer (score 0):

It's because that action cannot recognize by selenium since when you click on that plus button to upload it will give you a windows browse pop up. if you want to give a path to that you need to use Java robot(if you are using java).

this sendkeys command will work only for web elements and what you are getting here is not web element.

Sample code. This may work. if not please initiate a separate thread and run this code. because when you get that Windows pop up your execution will be held.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
StringSelection stringSelection = new     StringSelection("C:/Users/RAMASWAMY/Desktop/ModernDinningPlace.jpg");
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: Hi,   When i click on the plus button on the url, i am getting File Upload pop up. The File Upload popup can be handled by sendkeys() method or the AutoIT( 3 rd party tool).

Comment: Hi guys, I got my answer resolved. I used AutoIT  for uploading the   image. It is working well now. My mistake is " I took the path by forward slash, While giving the path in AutoIT code , we should use backward slash. But in Selenium we should use forward slash.

Comment: Pramod , Please share a document for the Robot class.